# Setting the default PDF viewer for rstudio

Tags: r, pdf, rstudio, knitr

Using knitr in Rstudio, when an .Rmd file is knit to PDF, the resulting file viewer is evince.  I would very much like to change this to okular, but I cannot find a way to make this happen.

Looking at the Sweave settings, I see "system viewer" noted for the preview, but okular is already set as my default system viewer.  I've also checked the default viewer with xdg-mime and okular is default there as well.  In all other instances, okular is the default but Rstudio/knitr always used evince.

How can I change this behavior?

Comment: Same, I'm using RStudio on Debian and opening PDF files from within RStudio. I would like to change the PDF viewer the other way, from Okular to Evince.

Answer (score 4):

I recently had this problem and found a potential solution.

First, check to see what the default PDF viewer is set to:

```
    Sys.getenv("R_PDFVIEWER")
```

Now, on my system this was "open", but it needed to be "xdg-open".

So, I changed the environmental variable:

```
    Sys.setenv(R_PDFVIEWER = "xdg-open")
```

This may be permanently set by:

```
    # Checking where your home directory is in R
    Sys.getenv('HOME')
```

Then in terminal, in the home directory:

```
    # Making an R environment file that runs at startup
    touch .Renviron

    # Add the environment variable change
    echo 'R_PDFVIEWER = xdg-open' >> .Renviron
```

Now, when R starts the correct PDF viewer should be used.

Comment: Sorry for the slow/late reply - tried this and it didn't work.  At this point, I've uninstalled Evince and Rstudio simply doesn't open the viewer at all.

Answer (score 4):

Works on Mac, R Studio version 1.2.1335

Opitons | Sweave | PDF Viewer : System viewer 
[image]

Comment: This does not work if you want to use anything other than Preview.app.

Answer (score 0):

## Rstudio setup

Same as you :

- Opitons | Sweave | PDF Viewer : System viewer

## OS Setup

Using file manager :

- Right-click some random *.pdf* file
- Open with... | Choose application...
- Select your favorite PDF viewer
- Set as default

---

*Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya

File manager: nemo

PDF Viewer: apvlv

RStudio 1.1.383*

Comment: Yep.  Tried that and it doesn't work.  When I do this, Okular is indicated as the default already, and Rstudio still uses Evince.  At this point, I've uninstalled Evince and Rstudio simply doesn't open the viewer at all.  I can easily enough open it myself and open the .pdf, but clearly Rstudio isn't working.

Comment: Please tell us about your OS and your desktop

Comment: Fedora 26 with Cinnamon desktop environment.